# Python Syntax One Line Loop

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to understand some code I saw online. I'm not really sure what the `\`s do. Is this making an array with a recursive call? Can you please help me put this into a multiple line loop so I can understand it?

```
actionList = [ \
        (self.miniMaxHelp(gameState.generateSuccessor(agentIndex, k), \
        newDepth, ind)[0], k) for k in gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex)]
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is a (rather complex) [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

The `\` at the end of the line is python's "Continue this on the next line" marker.  However, in this case, they are completely unnecessary as python will continue onto the next line if a set parenthesis, braces or square brackets aren't closed.

e.g.:

```
f = 1 + \
    2
```

Is the same as:

```
f = 1 + 2
```

Which is the same as:

```
f = (1 +
     2)
```

Similarly,

```
lst = [1, 2]
```

is the same as:

```
lst = [1, \
       2]
# OR
lst = [
  1,
  2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If answer comments would preserve formatting this would go there.  But I would surmise the backslashes were to maintain an 80 character width format without the odd structure like

```
actionList = [(self.miniMaxHelp(gameState.generateSuccessor(agentIndex, k), 
                                newDepth, ind)[0], k)
              for k in gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex)]
```

or the complete dismantling of that list comprehension into a `for loop`

```
actionList = []
for k in gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex):
    actionList.append((self.miniMaxHelp(gameState.generateSuccessor(agentIndex, k),
                                        newDepth, ind)[0], k))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what that piece of code does, in a more legible format:

```
actionList = []
for k in gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex):
    successor = gameState.generateSuccessor(agentIndex, k)
    x = self.miniMaxHelp(successor, newDepth, ind)[0]
    actionList.append((x, k))
```